# AspectJ pointcuts in Scala using SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, aspectj, sbt-aspectj

I'm trying to build a hello world example of using AspectJ pointcuts in Scala using the `sbt-aspectj` plugin. In my plugins.sbt I've added the plugin:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-aspectj" % "0.10.2")
```

and in my build.sbt, I've set it up as follows:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAspectj._

aspectjSettings

/* project settings */

fork in run := true

javaOptions in run <++= AspectjKeys.weaverOptions in Aspectj

products in Compile <++= products in Aspectj
```

Then I create a very simple AspectJ file defining a pointcut around one of my server classes:

package io.bigsense;

```
public aspect AspectLogger {

  private long start;

  pointcut conn() : call(* io.bigsense.server.TomcatServer.startServer(..));

  void around() : conn() {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Throwable t = null;
    try {
      proceed();
    }
    catch(Throwable _t) {
      t = _t;
    }
    long spent = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.println("Send time: " + spent);
    if (t != null) {
      throw new RuntimeException(t);
    }
  }

}
```

So that class and function do exist. But whenever I run sbt, I get the following message:

```
[info] Weaving 1 AspectJ source to /home/cassius/sensespace/BigSense/target/scala-2.10/aspectj/classes...
[warn] warning at /home/cassius/sensespace/BigSense/src/main/aspectj/AspectLogger.aj:11::0 advice defined in io.bigsense.AspectLogger has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
```

I've looked at a lot of examples and my pointcut looks correct. Why is it not being applied/weaved into my code at runtime?

**EDIT**: adding the command line arguments that sbt is launching java with:

```
/opt/oracle-jdk-bin-1.7.0.80/jre/bin/java
-javaagent:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars/aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar
-classpath
/home/cassius/sensespace/BigSense/target/scala-2.10/classes:/home/cassius/sensespace/BigSense/target/scala-2.10/aspectj/classes:/home/cassius/sensespace/BigSense/lib/ij.jar:/home/cassius/sensespace/BigSense/lib/eproperties-1.1.3.jar:/home/cassius/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.4/lib/scala-library.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/twirl-api_2.10/jars/twirl-api_2.10-1.0.4.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/jars/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/jars/aspectjrt-1.8.5.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-beans/jars/spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-core/jars/spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-asm/jars/spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/commons-logging/commons-logging/jars/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-context/jars/spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-aop/jars/spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/aopalliance/aopalliance/jars/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-expression/jars/spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/cglib/cglib/jars/cglib-2.2.2.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/asm/asm/jars/asm-3.3.1.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/commons-io/commons-io/jars/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds/jars/jtds-1.2.4.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/com.jolbox/bonecp/bundles/bonecp-0.7.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/jars/guava-r08.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/log4j/log4j/bundles/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.scalaj/scalaj-collection_2.10/jars/scalaj-collection_2.10-1.5.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15/jars/bcprov-jdk15-140.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.postgresql/postgresql/jars/postgresql-9.4-1201-jdbc41.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.postgis/postgis-jdbc/jars/postgis-jdbc-1.3.3.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.postgis/postgis-stubs/jars/postgis-stubs-1.3.3.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/postgresql/postgresql/jars/postgresql-8.3-603.jdbc4.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/mysql/mysql-connector-java/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/jars/jetty-server-9.1.4.v20140401.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/jars/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http/jars/jetty-http-9.1.4.v20140401.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util/jars/jetty-util-9.1.4.v20140401.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io/jars/jetty-io-9.1.4.v20140401.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlet/jars/jetty-servlet-9.1.4.v20140401.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-security/jars/jetty-security-9.1.4.v20140401.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-webapp/jars/jetty-webapp-9.1.4.v20140401.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-xml/jars/jetty-xml-9.1.4.v20140401.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.rogach/scallop_2.10/jars/scallop_2.10-0.9.5.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.10.3.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/jars/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.53.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/jars/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.53.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/jars/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.53.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/jars/tomcat-embed-el-7.0.53.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler/ecj/jars/ecj-P20140317-1600.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/jars/commons-compress-1.6.jar:/home/cassius/.ivy2/cache/org.tukaani/xz/jars/xz-1.4.jar
io.bigsense.server.BigSenseServer
-c
../bs-env/mssql-vm.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through some of the other example projects and discovered that I was missing the following from my `build.sbt`

```
AspectjKeys.inputs in Aspectj <+= compiledClasses

products in Compile <<= products in Aspectj

products in Runtime <<= products in Compile
```

This places the compiled sources within the inpath for AspectJ.

Comment: As I said: the *inpath*. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`[Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]` always means that the AspectJ weaver/compiler does not see any joinpoints matching your pointcut on its *inpath*.

In this case, it means that no line of code doing a call to `* io.bigsense.server.TomcatServer.startServer(..)` is found. Probably the call is not made from your own source code but from some 3rd party library not woven by AspectJ. Consequently, you either need to weave the calling code or you should not be surprised that you get this warning. `;-)`

If you think that I am wrong, please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for me to reproduce your problem.

Comment: That class exists. You can find it here: https://github.com/BigSense/BigSense/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/bigsense/server/TomcatServer.scala  What's the correct pointcut for that class; or better yet, what's a generic pointcut to get every function in that class?

Comment: Please re-read my answer carefully. I did not say that the class does not exist. I said that the caller(s) of that class (the ones you want to intercept) are not on AspectJ's *inpath*. Again, please provide an SSCCE. Otherwise I can hardly say anthing more substantial about the cause of your problem. With an SSCCE I can, I promise.

Comment: My question is specifically about the sbt-aspectj plugin. This is my first time using AspectJ (trying to migrate off of Spring AOP). I've added the command line that SBT runs. I see the inpath missing, so I'm guessing this is either bug in sbt-aspectj or missing documentation. I've opened an issue on its tracker.

Comment: Discovered the answer. See my answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am using (on 2023) an JSF app and the method called is called by JSF page and not by other java classes.

Comment: Behind a JSF page is Java code, hence the "J" in JSF. so the call comes from another Java (or Scala, Kotlin or another JVM language) class.

Answer (score 1):

For sbt 0.13.16 now it's

```
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.sbt" % "sbt-aspectj" % "0.11.0")
```

in plugins.sbt and

```
import com.lightbend.sbt.SbtAspectj._

scalaVersion := "2.12.3"

aspectjSettings

aspectjInputs in Aspectj += (aspectjCompiledClasses in Aspectj).value

products in Compile := (products in Aspectj).value

products in Runtime := (products in Compile).value
```

in build.sbt.